# Как запустить программу требующую sudo с рабочего стола кликом мыши по иконке?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Простая задача: есть программа на C++ которая работает с mmap и с графической оболочкой (создает окно). Программа создается для ограниченных в познании компьютеров людей и нужно чтобы она запускалась с рабочего стола кликом мыши по иконке.

Я создал на рабочем столе start.sh и прописал ему chmod ugo+x

```
#!/bin/bash
cd my
sudo ./a.out
```

Если написать в терминале sudo ./start.sh то все работает.
А если с рабочего стола мышью нажать на иконку, то 3 кнопки: Open, Execute, Execute in Terminal.
То есть а где кнопка типо Execute with sudo? При запуске с рабочего стола mmap ругается и требует sudo. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.
Система Debian 9.9 оболочка lxqt.

Можно ли запустить скрипт с рабочего стола с sudo?

Или если нельзя, то может можно сделать чтобы система запускалась от root и не требовала sudo для mmap?

Или вообще как то сделать чтобы mmap не требовал sudo?

Или может можно хотя бы запускать программу с sudo при старте системы и как это сделать чтобы при этом окно успевало появляться в графической оболочке?

Comment: mmap не требует sudo сама по себе

Comment: возможно тогда open требует? в общем без sudo когда я обращаюсь к памяти которую mmap вернул у меня программа закрывается и там что то пишет про sudo на миллисекунду не успеваю прочитать

Comment: да open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC); возращает -1

Comment: Это явно проблема XY, пишите лучше про то, что вы хотите сделать, а не про то, как вы пытаетесь это сделать.

Comment: ну так в названии вопроса все написано

Comment: /dev/mem — это для драйверов устройств. Что именно ваша программа пытается делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу несколько путей.

1. Передать приложение руту и выставить UID бит. Тогда процесс запущенного приложения будет выполняться от имени рута. Соответственно, приложение имеет полный доступ ко всем возможностям ОС.

```
sudo chown root:root my/a.out
sudo chmod u+s my/a.out
```

Этот способ работает, но считается просто капец каким небезопасным.

2. Вместо `sudo` использовать графическую обёртку, которая спросит пароль при запуске.

Debian у меня нет. В Ubuntu последних версий это `pkexec`.

```
$ pkexec env DISPAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORUTY /full/path/to/a.out
```

Эта команда спросит пароль (графически) и запустит ваш `a.out` от имени `root`.

Пример:

```
user$ pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORUTY /usr/bin/xterm
```

Работает, открывает xterm от имени `root`

3. Дать процессу привилегии [`cap_sys_rawio`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html#:%7E:text=using%20kcmp(2).-,CAP_SYS_RAWIO,-*%20Perform%20I/O) и `cap_dac_override` (ХЗ как capability переводят русских мануалах, я перевёл как *привилегия*)

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio,cap_dac_override+ep ./my/a.out
```

С этими двумя фичам ваш процесс сможет открыть любой файл. В том числе  `/dev/mem`. Если `open("/dev/mem")` - единственная операция, которая требует привилегий, то процесс работать будет.

Пример:

```
cp /usr/bin/head .
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio,cap_dac_override+ep ./head
./head -c 32 /dev/mem | hexdump -C
```

Этот скрипт выводит первые 32 байта /dev/mem

Если же взять исходный `head` без привилегий

```
/usr/bin/head -c 32 /dev/mem | hexdump -C
```

то будет ошибка

```
/usr/bin/head: cannot open '/dev/mem' for reading: Permission denied
```

Comment: а раньше был gksu/gksudu/kdesu, но потом решили, что это небезопасно...

Comment: спасибо большое ошибку у меня не выдал только 1 вариант но и его достаточно для решения) в 3 у меня почему то пишет что a.out это ссылка и не хочет над ним что либо делать, второе у меня только из под рута работает, а так пишет после ввода пароля is need to run as the super user PolicyDeamon no session for coockie GDBus.error ...

Comment: @LuaКолдун странно это. У меня в Ubuntu 20 все три работают. Я добавил в 3 пример. Проверьте, должно работать. Что касается 2, то возможно LXQt не стартует dbus?